# databricks copy into csv command

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-sql

```
COPY INTO dev_stg.mtip.table1
FROM '/Volumes/prd_stg/ext-raw/25714_Table1.CSV'
FILEFORMAT = csv
COPY_OPTIONS ('inferSchema' = 'true','header'='true')
```

Table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE dev_stg.mtip.Table1 (
    PlayerName STRING,
    SiteNumber STRING
)
```

Why am I getting this error

```
schema mismatch was detected while copying into the Delta table (Table: `dev_stg`.`mtip`.`table1`).
This may indicate an issue with the incoming data, or the Delta table schema can be evolved automatically according to the incoming data by setting:
COPY_OPTIONS ('mergeSchema' = 'true')

Schema difference:
Incoming schema is missing field(s): PlayerName, SiteNumber , 
Incoming schema has additional field(s): _c0, _c2, _c3,
```

When I use the mergeSchema option I get a table

```
CREATE TABLE dev_stg.mtip.Table1 (
    PlayerName STRING,
    SiteNumber STRING,
    _c0        STRING
)
```

When I would like to copy the contents of the csv into the table.

Comment: The error tells you the problem: you don't have `PlayerName` or `SiteNumber` in your source data. Without doing any data modification/projection, there's no way to match fields.

Comment: I do have PlayerName, SiteNumber as when I use the below option I can see them        
 spark.read.option("delimiter", ",").option("header", True).csv

Comment: I have been able to use the expression list to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is due to a schema mismatch, meaning you haven't provided a **header** in **FORMAT_OPTIONS**. As a result, it takes the following as header:

```
_c0, _c2, _c3,
```

and displays missing fields and additional fields.

After adding **FORMAT_OPTIONS** to the header, it works and raises an exception for additional fields. To address this, you can either set **mergeSchema** to true in **COPY_OPTIONS** or, if you don't want the additional column, use a SELECT statement as you have already done.

```sql
COPY INTO player1 FROM (SELECT PlayerName, SiteNumber from 'path/autoloader/employee_data_1.csv')
  FILEFORMAT = CSV
  FORMAT_OPTIONS ('header'='true')
```

Output:
Data in the `csv` file.

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to use the expression list to resolve this

```
          COPY INTO dev_stg.mtip.table1 FROM  (  SELECT 
            PlayerName ::String as PlayerName  from mycsv )
            FILEFORMAT = CSV
            FORMAT_OPTIONS ('header'='true')
            COPY_OPTIONS ('mergeSchema'='true')
```